# Designing a server that performs an action every X minutes

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

Good Day,

I am required to write a java server that performs an action every X minutes. The action is to check a database to see if the current/system time matches any of the times in a database, and  to pull out those items, and send a TCP message to them.

Hencen, the database call is local on the machine, so that is no problem. However, at least 10 TCP calls need to be sent out simultaneously. Hence, the tick may actually need to occur on it's own thread. Can I have some suggestions?

Do I need a thread pool?

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do is create a schedular job and run that job every x minutes. so that job will be perform every x minutes and you need to define your task in job to perform for more info [click here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/)

Answer (score 0):

I would  use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or else I would use the [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) - the former is more lightweight, while the latter is (optionally) durable (meaning that scheduled tasks will be saved to a database and reloaded when your program restarts).

Answer (score 0):

Either [TimerTask](http://bip.weizmann.ac.il/course/prog2/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html) (or) [ScheduledExecutorServices](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) implementations would be best options for this task. Yes, I think thread pool would be best option because you don't need to create 10 threads every X minutes.

Comment: Okay I have used ScheduledExecutorServices and it works great. But how do i do sending of multiple TCP messages/packets at the same time?